# sorting for 2 arraylist that each of them represent x and y coordinate

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists

xVal : [9 8 6 5 4 3 2 -10 ]
yVal : [3 6 5 7 9 1 8  10 ]

I want to sort xVal in ascending order and also have corresponding yVal to move as xVal is sorted.

So result would be

xVal : [-10 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 ]
yVal : [ 10 8 1 9 7 5 6 3 ]

Thank you for time to explain it

Comment: Make life simple for your self and Create a class with x and y fields , construct however many objects needed then store it into a list and sort that.

Comment: Don't use parallel arrays. Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it. Create a class with the pair of x,y values, or use the built-in one: [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to use a different data structure here. You can create an own data type (POJO) for the x/y coordinates and then you can sort the list in a "normal" Java way.

This is the POJO what you can use:

```
public class Coordinate {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + x + ", " + y + "] ";
    }
}
```

And the main program which initialzes the list, sorts the coordinades based on X coordinate and then shows the result:

```
public class SortDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // init the list
        List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(9, 3));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(8, 6));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(6, 5));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(5, 7));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(4, 9));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(3, 1));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(2, 8));
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(-10, 10));

        // sort
        Collections.sort(coordinates, (coordinate1, coordinate2) -> coordinate1.x - coordinate2.x);

        // display the content of the sorted list
        System.out.println(coordinates);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[-10, 10] , [2, 8] , [3, 1] , [4, 9] , [5, 7] , [6, 5] , [8, 6] , [9, 3]
```

**EDIT**

[**toString()**:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

For example:

```
Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(-10, 10);
System.out.println(coordinate);
```

OR

```
Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(-10, 10);
System.out.println(coordinate.toString());
```

You can check it in DEBUG mode in your IDE.

**Sort**

The mentioned short form of collection sort is equivalent with this:

```
class MySort implements Comparator<Student> {
    public int compare(Coordinate coordinate1, Coordinate coordinate2) {
        return coordinate1.x - coordinate2.x;
    }
}

// how to use
Collections.sort(coordinates, new MySort());
```

[API doc of compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: Why getters and setters if you can make them public instead? No need for false encapsulation.

Comment: Indead, we do not need getters/setters in this case. I am going to remove them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!
Just quick question on when to use "toString" method and 

can't understand this part
"        Collections.sort(coordinates, (coordinate1, coordinate2) -> coordinate1.x - coordinate2.x);"
** I know Collections.sort(arraylist object name) will do sorting but what are you doing with (coordinate1, coordinate2) -> coordinate1.x - coordinate2.x part?

Comment: @zappee : thanks for explaining it! it makes more sense now :-)